# Which Regex to parse search hints

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex fu is terrible. I want to build a smart search where I can give hints to the search engine on what to search on which property.

Something like this:

Search input: *location: London*

-> `["London"]`

Search input: *location: London, New York*

-> `["London", "New York"]`

Search input: *location: London tags: Bar*

-> `["London"]`

-> `["Bar"]`

Search input: *location: London, New York tags: Bar, Club*

-> `["London", "New York"]`

-> `["Bar", "Club"]`

I wonder how should the regex look like to parse the user input like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just split the string, like this:

```
> var s = "location: London, New York tags: Bar, Club";
> var splitted = s.split(/location: | tags: /);
> splitted[1].split(', ')
["London", "New York"]
> splitted[2].split(', ')
["Bar", "Club"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a little bit of RegEx and Split.

```
var input = 'location: London, New York tags: Bar, Club'; // example

var arrays = input.split(/\s*\w+:\s*/);

arrays.forEach(function (val, idx, arr) {
    arr[idx] = val.split(/,\s*/);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a different approach. Maybe it's just me not getting the other solutions correctly but for me it seems as if there's no way to tell which target words belong to which key.

If `location: London, New York tags: Bar, Club`

will be switched to `tags: Bar, Club location: London, New York`

how would I now which target words belong to `location` and which to `tags`?

So what I did is this:

```
var locationMatch = searchString.match(/location:(((?!tags:)[-A-Za-z0-9, ])+)/);
//locationMatch[1] are the target words for "location"

var tagsMatch = searchString.match(/tags:(((?!location:)[-A-Za-z0-9, ])+)/);
//tagsMatch[1] are the target words for "tags"
```

I guess there`s an easier approach but I'm far from being a regex pro.